# Regular Expression in C++

Tags: c++, regex, algorithm

I want to write C++ library for Regular Expression. I know there are many libraries available but I want to learn theory behind regular expression and implemented it by myself.

Can anybody please guide on what should I start with.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern

Comment: @Crazy, the theory of regular expressions is much more closely related to deterministic finite automata and regular languages than to general interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html has a good explanation of the two major approaches to regular expressions, their trade-offs, and how to make the faster one (DFAs) usable in a lot of cases that most implementations fail to use them for.

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth looking into book "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" that deeply covers techniques behind regular expression parsing  (and the theory regarding DFAs and NDFAs). It has good pseudo-code examples that could help in creating own implementation

Answer (score 1):

As long as you want to write the library, then in addition to referencing the excellent resources other answers give, you might explore implementing the C++0x specification for regular expressions found in chapter 28 of [N3225](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, this is THE book on the subject of regular expressions. It may not get you all the way to figuring out how to code up a C++ library, but the explanation of the theory is excellent and it includes a lot of examples for the practical application of regular expressions in many contexts.

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126?green=9514625548&cmp=af-mybuy-9780596528126.IP

Comment: It is a classic, but the author of the book unfortunately didn't pay enough attention to the theory of regular expressions and makes some wildly incorrect claims.

Comment: Interesting, I'd like to read more about that if you have any links that go into detail.

Comment: The techniques shown in http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html can be modified to make a DFA that tracks capturing parentheses which runs in time O(n).  Jefferey Friedl believed (and to my knowledge still believes) that nobody knows how to do it faster than O(n*n).

Answer (score 0):

[In the Microsoft implementation of the TR1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982198.aspx), which is the report for the next C++0x standard, there is the `<regex>` library available.

the TR1 is available for visual 2008, and by default in visual 2010.

But that's interesting only if you plan to program on the windows plateform, of course.

I don't know if g++ includes the `<regex>` library in its tr1 implementation. I guess yes, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I have used book [http://www.amazon.com/Compiler-Design-C-Prentice-Hall-software/dp/0131550454](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131550454)
and implemented here http://code.google.com/p/regex/